# handle dates and concatenate strings in dplyr (SQL)

Tags: sql, r, date, dplyr

I have a database with `YEAR` and `DOY` (day of the year) columns. I'd like to add a extra column `DATE`, e.g.

```
mutate(data, DATE = date(julianday(YEAR || '-01-01'), '+'||(DOY-1)||' day'))
```

But that does not work, probably because the SQL string concatenation "||" is transformed to an "OR". how would you do that?

In another case I have to convert a string in a SQL date object. In R I would use `lubridate` and `ymd` is there a similarly simple way to do with `mutate` in dplyr (SQL)?

Christof

Comment: Try `%||%` it should be converted to `||`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutate` in dplyr modifies the result but does not modify the table in the database which I gather is what you want.

The question did not state which database is being used and this is important but in the absence of that SQLite is used below.

**1)** Here is code using the RSQLite package to update table `DF` in the database with a `DATE` column. `(DOY-1)` might be needed in place of `DOY` depending on the origin (0 or 1) of `DOY`.  You might need to cast `DOY` to integer too but in my run it worked without that.

```
library(RSQLite)

# create test database with a table DF
con <- dbConnect(SQLite())
DF <- data.frame(YEAR = 2014, DOY = 15)
dbWriteTable(con, "DF", DF)

# add DATE column to table DF and update its value
dbGetQuery(con, "alter table DF add column DATE")
dbGetQuery(con, "update DF 
                 set DATE = date(cast(YEAR as integer) || '-01-01', DOY || ' days')")
```

giving:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select * from DF")
##   YEAR DOY       DATE
## 1 2014  15 2014-01-16
```

**2)** If you do just want to modify the result and not the database itself then try this again assuming SQLite:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RSQLite)

# create database and add table DF to it
db <- src_sqlite(path = tempfile(), create = TRUE) # test database
DF <- data.frame(YEAR = 2014, DOY = 15) # test data
dbWriteTable(db$con, "DF", DF)

db_DF <- tbl(db, "DF")
db_DF %>% 
      mutate(DATE = sql("date(cast(YEAR as integer) || '-01-01', DOY || ' days')"))
```

**Update** (1) uses RSQLite and modifies database. (2) uses dplyr and does not.

Comment: thx, works fine on `data.frames`and with `sqldf`as in your example, but not with a dplyr `SQLiteConnection` it constructs a query like `SELECT "DATE", AS.DATE(PASTE0("YEAR", '-01-01')) + ("DOY" - 1.0) AS "DATE"` and SQL does not know anything about `paste0`and `as.date`

Comment: %||% is documented in the dplyr docu. but the , in the SQL date(...,...) seems to be a problem (! (to NOT), && and & to AND, || and | to OR, ^ to POWER, %>% to %, ceiling to CEIL, mean to AVG, var to VARIANCE, tolower to LOWER, toupper to UPPER and nchar to length. c and : keep their usual R behaviour so you can easily create vectors that are passed to sql. All other functions will be preserved as is. R’s infix functions (e.g. %like%) will be converted to their sql equivalents ... || is mapped to OR, but %||% is mapped to ||. )

Comment: @Grothendieck Maybe, but if not necessary I do not want to change the database or convert large amounts of data to an R object. ;)

Comment: Have revised to use RSQLite so that it operates to modify the database in place.

Comment: @Grothendieck Many thanks for your detailed help and describtions, it is a fine workaroundd for me